# Sign in/Sign up with Facebook - test users

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am fairly new to facebook integration. I got to add "Sign up/in with Facebook" option to register new users with my web site. I am following these steps: [Server-Side Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

1) Which account do I use to test this? Will my personal account be suspended or banned if I use it to play with the api?

2) To test the api, do I have to create test users like this? [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)

3) Also, to create test users, looks like I need to [authenticate as App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) Can someone explain why I should authenticate as app to create test users?

4) Sometimes, I get confused by the usage of the word "app". My website is not considered a Facebook app just because I use facebook to sign Up/In my users. Correct?

Comment: according to #1 how exactly will you be playing ?

Comment: Sign up. Then revoke access. Repeat several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No (if you are doing what you mentioned in the comments)
2. You don't have to create test users, but it helps to do so. For instance if you are testing wall posting from your app, then it's best to keep your personal profile/timeline clean. When you create an app, you also have the option to create test users in your app's settings page, so you don't need to do it programmatically.
3. Test users are associated with apps, so *probably* that's why you need app_access_token. However if you create test users with the ui in your app's settings page, then you don't need to mention any token.
4. Yes it is considered as one, that's how facebook's graph works, there are connections between external(3rd party) objects(they call them apps, as a generalization, after all your website can be called a web application) and facebook objects like users, pages etc. When you create an app you can see the different types/categories of apps that facebook lets you specify for your app. So it's just a name, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks bool.dev. Precise & helpful.